# Dynamic LINQ query against DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dynamic

I would like to summarize data in a SQL table in a DataTable for display in a DataGridView.  I'd like to use LINQ to query the table.

This SQL query produces the summary:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT * FROM vw_Trades WHERE NOT (dtExpDate < GETDATE())
)
SELECT szSymbol, dtFwdDate, sum(fQuantity) 
FROM CTE GROUP BY szSymbol, dtFwdDate 
HAVING SUM(fQuantity) <> 0
ORDER BY szSymbol, dtFwdDate
GO
```

I tried to use the System.Linq.Dynamic package but it appears to be obsolete.  Tried the System.Linq.Dynamic.Core package but can't find any documentation.  The catch is that I don't know at compile time what fields are going to be in the SELECT statement which makes it impossible to use the typed LINQ queries.

I can use dynamic SQL but wanted to use LINQ.  Is there a decent library for this or am I better off sticking with SQL?

Comment: I don't see anything "dynamic" in your query - which part are you thinking is "dynamic"?

Comment: If you need to work with `DataTable`s, you'd better stuck with ADO.NET and SQL.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the columns szSymbol, dtFwdDate, and SUM(fQuantity) might be different depending on user input.  So they might want just szSymbol and SUM(fQuantity) or different fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the CTE is necessary; you can express that SQL as just

```
SELECT szSymbol, dtFwdDate, sum(fQuantity) 
FROM vw_Trades 
WHERE NOT (dtExpDate < GETDATE())
GROUP BY szSymbol, dtFwdDate 
HAVING SUM(fQuantity) <> 0
ORDER BY szSymbol, dtFwdDate
```

The Linq equivalent would be something like:

```
from t in vw_Trades
where dtExpDate >= DateTime.Now
group by new { szSymbol, dtFwdDate } into g
select new {szSymbol, dtFwdDate, quantity = g.Sum(i => i.fQuantity) }
where quantity <> 0
```

Note that you can source a `DataGridView` directly from a query - there's no need to use a `DataTable` (in fact it makes it more complicated).

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify.  There are 22 fields in the trades table.  The query here picks out three.  It is possible the user will select from 3 to 22 fields.  You're right I don't need the CTE, that was in there for other reasons.

Comment: OK so you want to dynamically select the columns that are returned?